# How can I change visual studio code mouse click events?

Tags: visual-studio-code

> For exemple I want to set the editor mouse click. When I click a file
>   should be opened in a separate window, not when I double click on the
>   file.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that can be changed, can be changed with settings:

press F1:

[image]

You will see a list of settings you can search through:

[image]

Otherwise there might be a plugin for that, or you have to make a plugin yourself.